# java.io.FileNotFoundException json file can not find

Tags: java, json, spring-mvc

**The structure of my java web project is like this:**
[image]

When I use this code to get the json file,error message said **"Caused by: 
java.io.FileNotFoundException: 
....\resources\properties\highcharts_startYearWeek.json"**

**How can I get this JSON file and how to modify my code?**

Comment: Resources are not files. You should be using `Class.getResource()` and friends.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I use this code,the problem has been solved.**

```
 String jsonPath = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource("").getPath();
                  jsonPath = jsonPath + "properties/";
                  startYearWeek = JsonUtil.parseJsonFile(jsonPath+"highcharts_startYearWeek.json", "{startYearWeek}");
                  System.out.println("startYearWeek:"+startYearWeek);
```